# Why are xlop commands producing horizontally smashed output when using \RequirePackage{xlop} in a custom document class?

Tags: document-classes, letterspacing, xlop

test.tex:

```
\documentclass{testclass}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\opadd{34}{45}

\end{document}
```

testclass.cls:

```
\ProvidesClass{testclass}

\RequirePackage{xlop} 

\LoadClass{article}
```

is producing:

[image: Output of opadd command showing digits smashed together]

Whereas this version of test.tex using `\usepackage{xlop}` produces the expected result.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xlop}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\opadd{34}{45}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please, make the snippet into a minimal document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that reproduces the issue. In my experiment the output is as expected.

Comment: Done.  Narrowed it down to \usepackage vs \RequirePackage

Comment: What if you put `\LoadClass{article}` _before_ `\RequirePackage{xlop}` in your class? The package probably relies on some setup made by the class…

Comment: @cgnieder That fixes it.  Is this ordering you suggest a general requirement or best practice?  I ask because this is my first time running across the order of `\LoadClass` and `\RequirePackage` being an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xlop` package uses a length parameter called `\opcolumnwidth` that is initialized to `2ex` when the package is loaded.

If you do `\RequirePackage{xlop}` before `\LoadClass{article}` there is still no font active and so the column width is set to 0pt.

Actually, the setting is not really good anyway, because even changing the loading order the column width would be set to 2ex relative to the standard `article` font, which might not fit the font used in the document.

It may be better to reset the parameters at begin document, hence after the document font has been set.

```
\ProvidesClass{testclass}

\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{xlop}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \opset{columnwidth=2ex,lineheight=\baselineskip}%
}
```